# import nexus from diffrent sources

Tags: nexus

I have two instances of nexus server (2.14.0-1 and 3.16.1) Running on production.on the other side, we have created a new instance server Nexus 3.16.1 for our validation environment (an existing installation of Nexus Repository Manager 3.16.1 populated with data and configurationfor instance).
I'm looking on how to get my data ( copy them )  from my production environement (stored on booth server 2.14.0-1 and 3.16.1.) and put them to our validation environment.

Is there a way to import theses storage to the new environement destination . kind of import data from a source ( Nexus 2 / Nexus 3 )

Answer (score 0):

here is the answare to my question https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/236210187